# Show full list of php scripts on server

Tags: php, linux, apache

How i show full list of running php sripts on linux server? I see only httpd service, or PID but not specific php file source, i need analyze what script take more memory and fixed it. Thanks

Comment: Flagged for move to ServerFault, as this is a server administration question, not a programming question.

Comment: I think you can not see it if php run as apache module. If you configure php as cgi you can see the scripts I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. **Log all URLs** that are requested from your server and that end up in PHP scripts being executed
   You can use a PHP feature, which allows you to add a PHP script to any Apache request that is sent to PHP. You enable it by adding this to your root .htaccess:

   php_value auto_prepend_file append.php

In append.php you add a logging feature, where you can insert the URL requested, the time it took to generate the response and the max memory used. If you add this to a TAB separated file, you could import it in a DB table and see what is really happening on your server.

More info here: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-automatically-append-prepend/

1. **Debug what Apache is doing**, using strace
   You basically start Apache with strace. This will debug what operations Apache and subsequently PHP are doing. Watch out, as there is a lot of noise in the debug output.

More info here: http://bobcares.com/blog/?p=103